# compiling Fortran program and compiler/libraries

Tags: makefile, fortran, mpi

I am trying to make a [Fortran90-program](https://code.google.com/p/mplabs/wiki/QuickInstall) and I have installed the necessary libraries (OpenMPI v1.8 and gfortran). When I run `make` I get the error

`No underlying compiler was specified in the wrapper compiler data file
(e.g., mpicc-wrapper-data.txt)`

What does this mean and what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: It means that if you open that file you will fail to find within it the name and location of your compiler.  Correct that mistake and you should be good to go.  Before you ask, no, I don't know how to put that information into that file.  But OpenMPI is relatively well documented, use your favourite search engine for further guidance.

Comment: Use make -d.  It will tell you what it is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your installation of OpenMPI didn't come with a Fortran compiler (which is common, especially on OS X).  Getting gfortran by itself doesn't mean your OpenMPI will find it.

Try building OpenMPI yourself with the GCC compiler suite; it's pretty easy and is explained well at open-mpi.org.  Basically, you download and unpack the tarball, then configure OpenMPI with something like

```
mpi-base-dir $./configure --prefix=$HOME/openmpi-1.8 CC=gcc CXX=g++ FC=gfortran
mpi-base-dir $make 
mpi-base-dir $make install
```

Answer (score 2):

> What does this mean

It means that no underlying compiler was specified in the wrapper compiler data file which is either `your-openmpi-dir/share/openmpi/mpif90-wrapper-data.txt` or `your-openmpi-dir/share/openmpi/mpifort-wrapper-data.txt`.

> what do I need to do to make it work

Open mentioned files and set `compiler=gfortran`.

Comment: In my case this solution did not work - there is apparently more to running configure with `FC=gfortran` than simply placing that compiler name in the wrapper data.  The compiler was found but not some of the needed includes, at least in compiling NAS parallel benchmarks.  Rerunning configure and make with the FC variable fixed it for me.  Upvoted anyway for explaining the error message.